# In a class constructor, is it better to explicitly initialize the fields, or to call setter methods, or is it all the same?

Tags: java, constructor

Is this better?

```
public MyClass(String item){
    this.item = item;
}
```

Or this?

```
public MyClass(String item){
    setItem(String item);
}
```

Or are they the same?

I have been taught both ways, but one professor said that the second method was more secure. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: the 2nd method is less secure as `setItem` can be overridden

Comment: Calling methods that a superclass could override in a constructor [is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors). That means **if** you want to call your setters, they should be `final`.